# How can I properly make a multilevel map using lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, collectors

I'm comparing files in folders (acceptor & sender) using JCIFS. During comparation two situations may occur:
- file not exists at acceptor
- file exists at acceptor

I need to get a map, where compared files are groupped by mentioned two types, so i could copy non-existing files or chech size and modification date of existing...

I want to make it using lambdas and streams, because i woult use parallel streams in near future, and it's also convinient...\

I've managed to make a working prototype method that checks whether file exists and creates a map:

```
    private Map<String, Boolean> compareFiles(String[] acceptor, String[] sender) {

        return Arrays.stream(sender)
                .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, Stream.of(acceptor).anyMatch(s::equals)))
Map.Entry::getValue)));
                .collect(collectingAndThen(
                        toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue),
                        Collections::<String,Boolean> unmodifiableMap));
    }
```

but i cant add higher level grouping by map value...

I have such a non-working piece of code:

```
    private Map<String, Boolean> compareFiles(String[] acceptor, String[] sender) {

        return Arrays.stream(sender)
                .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, Stream.of(acceptor).anyMatch(s::equals)))
                .collect(groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
    }
}
```

My code can't compile, because i missed something very important.. Could anyone help me please and exlain how to make this lambda correct?

P.S. arrays from method parameters are SmbFiles samba directories:

```
private final String master = "smb://192.168.1.118/mastershare/";
private final String node = "smb://192.168.1.118/nodeshare/";

SmbFile masterDir   = new SmbFile(master);
SmbFile nodeDir     = new SmbFile(node);

Map<Boolean, <Map<String, Boolean>>> resultingMap = compareFiles(masterDir, nodeDir);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collecting into nested maps with the same values, is not very useful. The resulting `Map<Boolean, Map<String, Boolean>>` can only have two keys, `true` and `false`. When you call `get(true)` on it, you’ll get a `Map<String, Boolean>` where all string keys redundantly map to `true`. Likewise, `get(false)` will give a you map where all values are `false`.

To me, it looks like you actually want

```
private Map<Boolean, Set<String>> compareFiles(String[] acceptor, String[] sender) {
    return Arrays.stream(sender)
        .collect(partitioningBy(Arrays.asList(acceptor)::contains, toSet()));
}
```

where `get(true)` gives you a set of all strings where the predicate evaluated to `true` and vice versa.

`partitioningBy` is an optimized version of `groupingBy` for `boolean` keys.

Note that `Stream.of(acceptor).anyMatch(s::equals)` is an overuse of Stream features. `Arrays(acceptor).contains(s)` is simpler and when being used as a predicate like `Arrays.asList(acceptor)::contains`, the expression `Arrays.asList(acceptor)` will get evaluated only once and a function calling `contains` on each evaluation is passed to the collector.

When `acceptor` gets large, you should not consider parallel processing, but replacing the linear search with a hash lookup

```
private Map<Boolean, Set<String>> compareFiles(String[] acceptor, String[] sender) {
    return Arrays.stream(sender)
        .collect(partitioningBy(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(acceptor))::contains, toSet()));
}
```

Again, the preparation work of `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(acceptor))` is only done once, whereas the `contains` invocation, done for every element of `sender`, will not depend on the size of `acceptor` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my problem. I had a type mismatch, so the working code is:

```
private Map<Boolean, Map<String, Boolean>> compareFiles(String[] acceptor, String[] sender) {

        return Arrays.stream(sender)
                .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, Stream.of(acceptor).anyMatch(s::equals)))
                .collect(collectingAndThen(
                        groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)),
                        Collections::<Boolean, Map<String, Boolean>> unmodifiableMap));
    }
```